# MySQL Query for amount of rows in the last 24 h

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to return the amount of rows, which where added in the last 24 hours to my database. The following code should actually work:

```
id_24h_back = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE datetime = now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;"
id_now = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE datetime = now();"
amount_rows = id_now - id_24h_back
```

I guess that this code would actually work and give me the result I need, but the problem is, that there isn't a row every second, so I get an empty set if 24h back datetime was e.g. 10:10:10, but the next existed row was added at 10:10:11.

**Edit:**
My solution looks now as follows.

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
x_time_back = current_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)      #24h
qry = "SELECT something FROM table_name WHERE x_datetime between " + str(x_time_back.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'")) + " and " + str(current_time.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"))
qry_res = db.engine.execute(qry)
```

Thank you anyway to all who tried to help. Also thank you to the people who downvoted my question without a reason.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE datetime > now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;` ?

Comment: Don't get why this is getting down votes...

Answer (score 2):

@mata has it right.  This will give you the count and the actual timestamp when your count started.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY since
  FROM table
 WHERE datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

For good performance with this, you'll need an index on your `datetime` column.

Pro tip: don't use data type names, like `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE`, or `DATETIME`, for column names. Instead use something like `datestamp` or `insertion_time` or some such thing.  It will make it easier to write and debug complex queries.